# I am using jsf, hibernate and Spring in my project and now i need to implement JBPM(JBOSS)

Tags: hibernate, spring, jsf, jsf-2, jbpm

hello I am using jsf 2.0, hibernate and Spring in my project and now i need to implement JBPM(JBOSS) and totally i am new to jbpm and using glassfish server so how can i add this stuff...

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy jBPM as a part of your web application. See [the instructions in the user guide](http://docs.jboss.com/jbpm/v4/userguide/html_single/#userwebapp) for jBPM 4.

PS: I don't mean to be rude but giving details about your environment is usually a good practice if you want to get useful answers e.g. the versions of GlassFish, the version of jBPM, details about your app (is it a war, an ear?).